# win32 in C# debug assertion failed CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c#, c, winapi

I am calling exported functions from a win32 dll in C#. I am trying to record audio and then get back the data in my C# program. As for the win32, the recording and playing all work, the problem is I get a debug assertion failed when I start the record now that I am trying to use global alloc so that the memory for the data is shared globally between both applications.

the C#:

```
[DllImport("\\Wave Editor\\Wave Editor\\lib\\Record.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
unsafe public static extern Boolean StartDialog(Byte** d);

unsafe private void OpenRecord(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    unsafe Byte** recordSamples = (Byte**)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1);

    if (StartDialog(recordSamples) == false)
        Debug.WriteLine("Dialog failed");
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("Dialog success");
}
```

The important parts of the win32 code relating to pSaveBuffer (the shared memory):

```
PBYTE pSaveBuffer;
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:

    // Allocate memory for save buffer
    pSaveBuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_SHARE, 1);
    return 0;
case MM_WIM_CLOSE:
    GlobalFree(pSaveBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The win32 function that creates the dialog:

```
BOOL StartDialog(BYTE** b)
{
    b = &pSaveBuffer;
    if (CreateDialog(hdll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_RECORD), NULL, DlgProc) == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The win32 header file:

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

#include <Windows.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#endif

EXPORT BOOL StartDialog(BYTE** p);
```

This isn't the actual layout of the code, I put like things closer together to try get the point across. I think CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block) means I'm overwriting someone's heap, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Please read the asserting method carefully. You give a a method a pointer which expects a pointer on the unmanaged Heap. Check from where the value comes from.

Comment: Which value are you referring to?

Comment: In `OpenRecord`, you're allocating memory and passing its address to `StartDialog`. That is, `b` holds the address of the buffer. However, the first thing you do in `StartDialog` is to assign `&pSaveBuffer` to `b` where `&pSaveBuffer` is the address of a variable that contains the address of another buffer! What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why both GlobalAlloc and Marshal.AllocHGlobal allocates only a single byte. If you cast to `Byte**`, you need at least space for one pointer (4 or 8 bytes depending on the process bitness).

Comment: The *CRT* in `CrtIsValidHeapPointer` suggests, that the CRT is performing a check. Since you allocated the memory using `AllocHGlobal` directly, without going through the CRT, the memory is not part of the heap controlled by the CRT. The pointer is not valid, as far as the CRT is concerned. You also don't seem to understand, why there are pointers to pointers. This usually indicates an *out* parameter, that is dereferenced and assigned a valid pointer.